# My React Native App for android requires way too many permissions

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I made a create-react-native-app app and published using the recommended way with expo. The app is on the google play store but during the process of submitting it for some reason it required me to have a ton of permissions. The app uses none of these so I want to know how I can get rid of these as it is confusing to users. Here is the list of current permissions:

Version 1.0.0 can access:
Contacts
read your contacts
Location
approximate location (network-based)
precise location (GPS and network-based)
Phone
read phone status and identity
Photos/Media/Files
read the contents of your USB storage
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
Storage
read the contents of your USB storage
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
Camera
take pictures and videos
Microphone
record audio
Device ID & call information
read phone status and identity
Other
manage document storage
receive data from Internet
view network connections
full network access
draw over other apps
control vibration
prevent device from sleeping
install shortcuts
read Google service configuration

Comment: Did you eject the app? Also some of those permissions come from a React Native [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5886) and should be removed

Answer (score 1):

it seems that react-native has this known issue. There's a discussion related to this here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5886

It looks like react-native adds some permissions by default. Due to the fact that you used `create-react-native-app`, you do not have access to the native code, which can be a problem. If you perform the `eject` action, and you check out the Android manifest file, there a lot of lines like the following:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

This defines which permissions you ask in your app. By deleting them, you remove them. Just be sure that those permissions are not actually needed!

Beware, performing an `eject` is a one way action, you can never go back.

Hope it helps! Regards,

For more information on Android permissions, please check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/index.html